# Python program for finding Prime Number

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to python programming and I was stuck with this program and was wondering how this would execute,

```
for i in range (2,30):
j=2
counter=0
print(i,j)
while j<i:
    if i%j==0:
        counter=1
        j=j+1
    else:
        j=j+1
if counter == 0:
    print(str(i)+" is a prime number")
else:
    counter = 0
```

am sure that when the code reaches `while j<i`, the value of both j and i is 2 and the condition should result in false coz 2 is not less than 2.

So how does this code execute perfectly and print the expected output ?

am sorry if I am being a noob :P

Comment: I think I read your question wrongly. I initially thought you were asking how to get the code working. But now I think you're asking why it *does* work. Which is it?

Comment: The first time round (i == 2) j == i so it skips the while loop completely and therefore deduces that 2 is prime. But then it loops again over i (if you fix the indentation) and it starts performing the code in the while loop for each iteration. As soon as you find a factor of i (where i%j==0) then you can exit the while loop because the job is done (proven *not* prime).

Comment: @Raith Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your question was. I'm happy to help further if you want any clarifications on how that code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, although the indentation is broken.

I've simplified your code ever so slightly to show that it's fine.

```
for i in range (2,30):
    j=2
    prime=1
    while j<i:
        if i%j==0:
            prime=0
            j = i
        j=j+1
    if prime == 1:
        print(str(i)+" is a prime number")
```

This is not an ideal solution, and there are many optimisations you can add, but it does the job.